# Writing fractions in number fields with coprime numerator and denominator

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a number field with ring of integers $R$ such that the class group of $R$ is non trivial. Then, is it possible that for all $k \in K$, we can write $k = a/b$ with $(a,b) = 1$ and $a,b \in R$?

Certainly if $R$ has trivial class group, this is possible but what about the general case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible: if we write $k=a/b$ with $a$, $b\in R$ then the ideal class of $\left<a,b\right>$ is an invariant of $k$, and this can be non-trivial, e.g., $k=\sqrt{-6}/2$.

Comment: By $\langle a,b\rangle$, do you mean the gcd of the ideals $(a),(b)$? Anyway, maybe my question was unclear but I was really looking for a proof that what I asked for is impossible for every number field $K$ with non trivial class group.

Comment: I mean the ideal generated by $a$ and $b$. In a Dedekind domain, every ideal can be generated by two generators.

Comment: Ah yes, the ideal class is an invariant! Great!